# "type error in conditional" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My original code is given below and works fine. I wanted to add range check of 'ind' and in the modified version I added an if statement. When I run it I get a "type error in conditional", and I THINK its because of the output defintion [[String]] not IO()?

Is there anyother way to check for the range of the value held in `ind` and produce an output like "error"/"outofrange" ?

**original code**

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
retrieve [] dat = [[]]
retrieve ind dat = [exC ind d | d <- dat]
```

**modified code**

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
retrieve [] dat = [[]]
retrieve ind dat = if ind>3
                       then putStrLn "not found"
                       else [exC ind d | d <- dat]
```

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `putStrLn` with `error`. That will cause your program to abort completely (unless something higher level catches the exception.)

The problem with what you've written is that you have declared a pure type, and then are trying to do IO, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually two errors in that code.

- You need to use `error`, because it has type `String -> a` instead of `String -> IO ()`
- You apply `>` to `[Int]` and `Int`. Assuming that you want to test whether `ind` has length at most 3, you will have to call `length`.

Example:

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
retrieve [] dat = [[]]
retrieve ind dat | length ind > 3 = error "not found"
                 | otherwise      = [exC ind d | d <- dat]
```

Comment: The second point doesn't have to be an error. He could have made [Int] an instance of the Ord typeclass. (but I don't think that is the case)

Comment: I think you mean making [Int] an instance of the *Num* typeclass, which would actually have worked, but would be a pretty weird thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

As described in Ganesh's post, you want to do IO in a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional), which isn't possible.

Ways to express your program (*you'll have to use `length ind > 3` anyway)

1 Use `error` (best way) as shown in the other posts

2 Use pattern guards (`non exhaustive patterns`-exception will occur)

3 Implement the IO properly:

```
retrieve ind dat = if ind >= 3
                    then do return [exC ind d | d <- dat ] 
                    else do putStrLn "error"; return [[]]
```

`retrieve` will have the type

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> IO [[String]]
```

4 Use `Maybe` to express that the computation may fail.

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> Maybe [[String]]
retrieve [] dat = [[]]
retrieve ind dat | length ind > 3 = Nothing
                 | otherwise      = Just [exC ind d | d <- dat]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern guard for this:

```
retrieve :: [Int] -> [[String]] -> [[String]]
retrieve [] dat = [[]]
retrieve ind dat | ind <= 3 = [exC ind d | d <- dat]
```

If you leave it like that you'll get a "Non-exhaustive patterns in function retrieve". You could also add another case with a custom error:

```
retrieve _ _ = error "Out of range"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `then` branch has type `IO ()`, the `else` has type `[[String]]`. The types of the two `if` branches are different and there is no way to give a type to the whole `if` that doesn't cause a type conflict with one of the branches.